# Swift permanent textbox

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I was wondering if there was a way to let the user enter a name in a text field so it would stay there even if you turn off your phone or quit out of the application.

Answer (score 0):

UITextField doesn't have any persistence mechanism of its own.  You'll need to code something to save and restore the value programmatically.  You may want to look into NSUserDefaults for a small piece of information like a name.